# DataReceviedHandler Error, maybe thread Problem

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, if-statement, serial-port

In the DataReceviedHandler of an serial port i'm testing if a bool is set. 
If not I'm sending the next block to the serial port.

The boolean is set by the event of class. In the picture you can see that the programm goes into the if-statement, although the bool is false. Is this a thread problem? What could I do?

[a busy cat http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/3324/boolh.png](http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/3324/boolh.png)

If tried this:

```
                lock (_syncLock)
                {
                    if (_wrEEPROM)
                    {
                        //Hier müssen die weiteren 128er Blöche übertragen werden
                        SerialControl.Port.Write(_yTestMod.CreateYModemBlock(wrEE.EEPROMar, _eepromBlockIndex), 0,
                                                 _yTestMod.CreateYModemBlock(wrEE.EEPROMar, 2).Length);
                        _eepromBlockIndex += 1;
                    }
                }
```

and this in the event:

```
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            _eeprom = false;
            _logger = false;
            _wrEEPROM = false;
        }
```

but it's still not working.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a lock(whatever) at the beginning of the switch?

Comment: Sorry that was misleading, I mean that the boolean ist set by the event of a class...

Comment: You will need a lock around writing _and_ around reading that bool... Maybe make a copy of it before the switch.

Comment: I have no experience with the lock statement, could you post example code?

Comment: The bool is false when you look at it. It was true when the if() statement was executed.

Comment: Either threading problem or just the compiler being stupid. If no mt is involved try renaming the `_wrEEPROM` var and performing a full rebuild. It is possible that the debugger is watching the `_wrEEPROM` but the compiler has produced code that is checking something else

Answer (score 1):

to the lock:

create a private field-variable:

```
private Object _syncLock = new Object();
```

and then where ever you set or read your "Flag"-variable use

```
lock(_syncLock)
{
  myFlag = true; // whatever
}
```

or

```
lock(_syncLock)
{
  return myFlag;
}
```

in your case wrap the hole handler for the event and your code shown above in such a lock to start with.

Comment: BTW: if you had post some code instead of this picture I could have posted some *real* code for your problem - but I'm way to lazy to retype some lines of your picture ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input, next time I post the code. But i wanted to show the state of the bool.

Comment: yes I know - and of course this is a concurency problem with a nice race. Have you tried the lock?

Comment: I have tried the lock, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you got still the same behaviour (is false and get into the if?) - is this the only code where you set the flag to false?

Comment: Still the same behaviour and this is the only code where set the flag to false...

Comment: @king There must be a point where _wrEEPROM is set to true. We're not seeing that yet.

Comment: Do I have to use lock, every time I want to set _wrEEPROM?

Comment: I'm now using it everywhere, but still no change -.-

Comment: this is rather unusual - try setting a breakpoint on every line containing _wrEEPROM and look at the runtime behaviour - is this set between the lines? You can also try to replace the _wrEEPROM bool variable with a ManualResetEvent or Monitor from the System.Threading namespace - this IS threadsafe and you don't need any look to work with it